# How to separate values from asp.net textbox with linebreak?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string

I'm trying to separate the values from an asp.net textbox which ends with line breaks. For example -

```
959100001
959100002
```

Those values must be inserted into an array like {95910001, 959100002} to do further calculation.

Any advices?

I'm using C# btw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string test = "959100001\r\n959100002\r\n";

foreach(var item in test.Split(new char []{'\r','\n'},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Prints:

```
959100001
959100002
```

Or as suggested by Mike:

```
test.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `String.split()` method which split string based upon `newline` delimiter and return `string[]` array. Further you can use `long.TryParse` or `int.TryParse` method to convert string to number (int/long) type.

Comment: And maybe Environment.NewLine Property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I had tried this in my environment. See below....

[image]

My code snippet for your question's answer is below.

```
string[] lines = txtline.Text.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

It works fine.....

Answer (score 0):

Not tested:

```
string[] lines = TextBox1.Text.Split(Environment.NewLine);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to separate them, you can simply call Split method:

```
string[] lines = TextBox1.Text.Split('\n', '\r');
```

if you also want to convert these values to integer, try this:

```
int[] lines = Array.ConvertAll<string, int>(TextBox1.Text.Split('\n', '\r'), Convert.ToInt32);
```